# LED blinking while loop not working AVR timer 0

Tags: microcontroller, avr, timer

It is strange and rare. I am trying to blink a LED at PD0 at 2hz, but it doesn't work. Seems to me that while loop doesn't work at all. I have triple checked the code. what is the problem here?

```
uint8_t c=0; 

int main(void){

DDRD= 1<<0 ;
TCCR0 = (1 << CS02) |  (1 << CS00); // (clk_i/o )/1024 ( Prescaler) 

TIMSK |= 1<< TOIE0;
sei();

  while (1){ 
  if ( c >=30 ) { PORTD ^= 1<<0; c=0; }                //61.035/30= 2.034 hz
  }

  }

ISR (TIMER0_OVF_vect){
  c++;   //16000000/1024/256=61.035 hz
  }
```

Of course, I know the solution. It's by adding a random line of code to the while loop, and it works again. Strange!! What would be the problem? compiler bug??

```
uint8_t c=0; 

int main(void){

DDRD= 1<<0 ;
TCCR0 = (1 << CS02) |  (1 << CS00); // (clk_i/o )/1024 ( Prescaler) 

TIMSK |= 1<< TOIE0;
sei();

  while (1){ 
  if ( c >=30 ) { PORTD ^= 1<<0; c=0; }                //61.035/30= 2.034 hz
  _NOP();
  }

  }

ISR (TIMER0_OVF_vect){
  c++;   //16000000/1024/256=61.035 hz
  }
```

Comment: c should be volatile, declare it as: volatile uint8_t c=0;

Comment: @BeB00 Yes, you are right, but why it still works even I don't declare it as volatile, when I added a random line of code to the while loop?

Comment: undefined behaviour will do that to you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By NOT declaring it volatile you give the compiler permission to optimise.

In the first loop, the compiler knows the value of C at all times, because nothing else in the loop can modify C (and it isn't volatile) so, because C is always 0, the loop doesn't need to do anything. The code is working perfectly because that's what you asked for.

In the second loop, you call a procedure (oops, void function) `NOP()` which could do absolutely anything. So, unless the compiler does whole program analysis over all the libraries (and it doesn't), how does it know if `NOP()` modifies C?

It doesn't, so it can't make any assumptions about C's value and has to re-fetch it from memory.

Ths second program isn't *working*, it does what you expect *by accident*.

If the "random additional line" didn't involve a call - e.g. it was an inline assembly `NOP` instruction, you would probably see different behaviour.

Declare C volatile.

Comment: In the first loop, changing c=0 to c=1 doesn't work either. Can't the compiler see c=1 there? Is there a way not to use volatile, because 1 byte of sRam is 1 byte.

Comment: Of course it can see C=1 there. But 1 is still less than 30, so...

Comment: Where else other than SRAM are you going to store c to share it between ISR and main loop? Alternatives : program the timer for the correct frequency, and you only need to store a boolean. I use Ada so it's trivial to pack 8 Booleans into a byte. In C it's a bit of a mess but you can do it if you have to.

Comment: actually, it loads c into sRam anyway. The code using volatile actually use 2 bytes less flash memory. Strange!

Comment: Not so strange, and a good lesson in the perils of "premature optimisation".